# JUnit Common setup with custom rollback rules

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a large integration test suite that takes a long time to run. Most of this is due to setup of data. So I need to reduce the amount of time it takes to setup the data for the tests.
After doing some analysis, I see that there groups of tests that have common setup (using @Before annotation for example).

Is there a way to set up some rollback rules in spring and junit so that the data can be set up within a transaction (so it can be rolled back), then each test runs and rolls back to this point. Therefore the set up is only required once. Then at the end of the group, the setup is rolled back?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit provides various [test fixtures](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-fixtures) to accomplish what you want. In JUnit 4, you can use the following:

- `@BeforeClass`: Executed once *before* the test *class* starts.
- `@AfterClass`: Executed once *after* the test *class* ends.
- `@Before`: Executed *before* each test *case* (`@Test`).
- `@After`: Executed *after* each test *case* (`@Test`).

Hence, you could use `@BeforeClass` for an one-time setup and `@Before`/`@After` for "rollbacks".